Gradle task is not up-to-date because of JavaExec and IntelliJ gradle runner
Problem
I have registered a JavaExec task which is sometimes up-to-date and sometimes not. This depends on executing this sometimes via IntelliJ, sometimes via command line.
Since my JavaExec task is quite expensive, it's annoying during development.
How to reproduce
Given I have a HelloWorld class with main method which prints out "Hello World". I define a JavaExec task in my gradle kotlin DSL file:
tasks.register<JavaExec>("minimal-reproducer") {
  mainClass.set("org.example.HelloWorld")
  classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
  inputs.files("src/main/resources")
  outputs.file("build/output.log")

  doFirst {
    println(jvmArgumentProviders.isEmpty())
  }
}

When I build that two times on the Command Line using gradlew minimal-reproducer --info, I get as output
# First run
> Task :minimal-reproducer
Caching disabled for task ':minimal-reproducer' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':minimal-reproducer' is not up-to-date because:
  No history is available.
true <-------- That's the important line
Starting process 'command '... org.example.HelloWorld
Successfully started process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
Hello World

# Second run
> Task :minimal-reproducer UP-TO-DATE
Caching disabled for task ':minimal-reproducer' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Skipping task ':minimal-reproducer' as it is up-to-date.

Now I trigger the exact same command over IntelliJ using the exact same gradle wrapper I get following output
# First run using Intellij
> Task :minimal-reproducer
Caching disabled for task ':minimal-reproducer' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':minimal-reproducer' is not up-to-date because:
  Input property 'jvmArgumentProviders.$0' has been added for task ':minimal-reproducer'
false  <--------- Here it is false, jvmArgumentProviders is not empty!!!
Starting process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''. Working directory: /Users/richardvogel/IdeaProjects/xsd-generation Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=DE -Duser.language=de -Duser.variant -cp /Users/richardvogel/IdeaProjects/xsd-generation/build/classes/java/main:/Users/richardvogel/IdeaProjects/xsd-generation/build/resources/main:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-properties/2.15.1/ba4ab1ab3be540b2e91060357d15b57fe4c663ff/jackson-dataformat-properties-2.15.1.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.15.1/ac9ba74d208faf356e4719a49e59c6ea9237c01d/jackson-databind-2.15.1.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.15.1/92a90d3739e970e03b5971839e4fe51f13c1fa3/jackson-annotations-2.15.1.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.15.1/241c054ba8503de092a12acad9f083dd39935cc0/jackson-core-2.15.1.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.15.1/ab2078805370360d32c77f1ba46dc9098f84daa6/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.15.1.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/4.0.0/1f672b28726bc355cbbde7aed7001fe024fc6f13/jaxb-runtime-4.0.0.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-core/4.0.0/83ab64d327198b2facd4071415d782ebc69469a1/jaxb-core-4.0.0.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.0/bbb399208d288b15ec101fa4fcfc4bd77cedc97a/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/8531ad5ac454cc2deb9d4d32c40c4d7451939b5d/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.angus/angus-activation/1.0.0/f0ceddd49f92109fbfad9125e958f5bfd3f2aa1/angus-activation-1.0.0.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.0/a58861b5deac5e151140511cf57d6b80a83f2d20/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.0.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/85262acf3ca9816f9537ca47d5adeabaead7cb16/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/txw2/4.0.0/afa5e81b5a9a390c98651a3da71c7f4cde14bcf0/txw2-4.0.0.jar:/Users/richardvogel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime/4.1.1/9b3769c76235bc283b060da4fae2318c6d53f07e/istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar org.example.HelloWorld
Successfully started process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
Hello World

# Second run using IntelliJ
> Task :minimal-reproducer UP-TO-DATE
Caching disabled for task ':minimal-reproducer' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Skipping task ':minimal-reproducer' as it is up-to-date.

Since using IntelliJ the jvmArgumentProviders are not empty. Therefore the task is never up-to-date when I run it alternately over the command line and over IntelliJ.
Analysis
When I debugged my gradle task I see following code inside of /private/var/folders/1x/.../T/ijresolvers3.gradle (on Mac) and C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/1/ijresolvers13.gradle on Windows.
//-- Generated by org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleJava.configuration.KotlinGradleCoroutineDebugProjectResolver
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { TaskExecutionGraph taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.allTasks.each { Task task ->
        if (!(task instanceof Test || task instanceof JavaExec)) return
        
        for (arg in task.getJvmArgs()) {
            if (arg == "-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off") {
                return
            }
        }

        FileCollection taskClasspath = task.classpath
        task.jvmArgumentProviders.add(new CommandLineArgumentProvider() {
            private static def VERSION_PATTERN = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(/(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.(\d+))?.*/)
        
            @Override
            Iterable<String> asArguments() {
                List<String> emptyList = Collections.emptyList()
                if (System.getProperty("idea.debugger.dispatch.port") == null) return emptyList
                def kotlinxCoroutinesCoreJar = taskClasspath.find { it.name.startsWith("kotlinx-coroutines-core") && !it.name.contains("sources") }
                if (kotlinxCoroutinesCoreJar == null) return emptyList
                def results = (kotlinxCoroutinesCoreJar.getName() =~ /kotlinx-coroutines-core(\-jvm)?-(\d[\w\.\-]+)\.jar$/).findAll()
                if (results.isEmpty()) return emptyList
                String version = results.first()[2]
                def matcher = VERSION_PATTERN.matcher(version)
                try {
                    if (!matcher.matches()) return emptyList
                    int major = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) 
                    int minor = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2))
                    int patch = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(4) ?: "0")
                    if (major < 1 || (major == 1 && (minor < 5 || (minor == 5 && patch < 1)))) return emptyList
                } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
                    return emptyList
                }
                return ["-javaagent:${kotlinxCoroutinesCoreJar?.absolutePath}", "-ea"]
            }
        })
    }
}

I think this IntelliJ magic adds an jvmArgumentProvider to the JavaExec task. Do you know how to bypass this?

Although a little annoying, it's not too much work to just write your own task to invoke a process and bypass JavaExec. The function Project.javaexec() (now ExecOperations.javaexec()) is useful here

Thanks to @simon-jacobs I found the solution. Removing the JavaExec task type and performing it over project.javaexec.
tasks.register("minimal-reproducer") {
  dependsOn("classes")
  inputs.files("src/main/java") // Declare inputs (e.g., resources)
  outputs.file("build/output.log")   // Declare an output file

  doFirst {
    project.javaexec {
      mainClass.set("org.example.HelloWorld")
      classpath = project.sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
      errorOutput = System.err
      isIgnoreExitValue = false
    }
  }
}

